# Tango Without Android?

Tags: android, nvidia, google-project-tango

Is it possible to compile project Tango to run on a device that does not have android installed?

I'd like to run Tango on an Nvidia Jetson TX2. Nvidia won't port Android to the Jetson. I've got an Intel Realsense ZR300 on order, which should provide the necessary inputs to Tango.

Comment: I don't believe that Project Tango is open source so you would need to reach out to Google directly to get access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Right now Tango is only running on Android.

But we understand your interest, we will investigate the possibility to porting Tango to other platform. We will let you know if we have the update.

If you really want to know more details, 
please reach to tango-help@google.com.
Thanks.